How to add multiple SSO domains to Storyblok
I work at an agency that building a Storyblok managed website for a client. The client wants to use SSO for its own employees when logging into Stoyblok. We, the agency, do not have email addresses on their domain so we cannot use their SSO setup.
Is there a way to connect two domains to the same space so we can use our own email addresses and our client can use theirs?
